# Tuple within Tuple Returning False

Tags: python, boolean, tuples

Can someone please explain why the following is False?

```
x = (1, 2, (3, 'John', 4), 'Hi')

print 3 in x
```

Is it because 3 is in within another tuple? But if this is the case, isn't the number 3 still technically in x??

Comment: That is behaving exactly how it was designed. No `3` is not `in x`, `(3, 'John', 4)` is `in x`.

Comment: Try `print (3, 'John', 4) in x`. `(3, 'John', 4)` is in `x` actually :)

Comment: So: yes, it is because 3 is within another tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in` operator doesn't search recursively through sub-tuples. Conceptually, `in` simply iterates over each item `i` in the tuple and checks if `x == i`. If it checked for `x in i` in addition to `x == i` then it would find 3, but it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

`x` contains 4 items: the integer `1`, the integer `2`, the tuple `(3, 'John', 4)`, and the string `'Hi'`, so the integer `3` is not in `x`.

However `3 in x[2]` is `True`.